# Best Rails/Ajax Effect/Animation Library

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, user-interface, effect

What javascript effect/ui libraries are the best that also have Rails helpers and all that?

Which ones do you use.  Seems like people use jQuery with either scriptaculous or yui for the interface elements...  Is there anything that's particularly easy or best that's supported in a Rails gem or something similar that you recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm comfortable with jQuery for Rails [jRails](http://github.com/aaronchi/jrails) plugin.